# Kendo grid date filter localization

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I try since one hour or more to change the localization of the date column filter type language. And I can't.

Here what I have :

On my _Layout : `kendo.culture("fr-FR");`

And when I load a page (anywhere on the app) :

[image: When I check filters in chrome console]

But in the filter combo :

[image: When I want filter the date column]

What is happening and what am I missing ?

**Edit :**

I forgot to say that the date filters are the only ones with this problem, string and number filters are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it !

I don't understand what exactly is the problem here...
I load the good culture file, number and string filters are ok, but not the date.

But in the kendo settings I have the good so...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".k-grid").each(function () {
        var grid = $(this).data("kendoGrid");
        if (grid) {
            grid.bind("filterMenuInit", onFilterMenuInit);
        }
    });
});

function onFilterMenuInit(e) {
    if (this.dataSource.options.schema.model.fields[e.field].type === 'date') {
        var filters = new Array();
        var raw = kendo.ui.FilterMenu.prototype.options.operators.date;
        for (var property in raw) {
            if (raw.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                filters.push({ value: property, text: raw[property] });
            }
        }
        e.container.find("select:eq(0)").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.data(filters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load in the French version of the Kendo message script file:

`<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/js/messages/kendo.messages.fr-FR.min.js"></script>`

[Sample Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UGUzi)

### EDIT

Dojo updated with [date example](http://dojo.telerik.com/UGUzi/2).

NOTE: Date filter options are also in the specified language.

Comment: I already have this file loaded, that's why I can see the good words in the console. The problem is that the grid load the wrong translations...

Comment: Can you make a dojo example to demonstrate the problem you are having?

Comment: I can't, I'm on kendo asp.net :/, but all is in the OP. I have a column with DateTime and when my pages are loaded the `kendo.ui.FilterMenu.prototype.options.operators.date` are corects when I check them in the console but in my grid they are invalid, they work but they are in english. And they are the only ones, string and number are corrects.

Comment: I have updated dojo with a date example - where the filters are also displayed in French. Additionally, your OP could be extended to show the code you are using to instantiate the grid, along with the scripts you have included.

Comment: Here is my grid declaration : https://zerobin.net/?442f493aec37f11f#WQqgnwVAUjGghq9D5hgTW0MydiHBcRFL3IAqXzpp/bI=

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary about the grid setup.. Was incase there was any additional config of the languages that may be overriding the `messages` script.. What about the scripts included on the page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145648/discussion-between-shadam-and-sandman).